# How to append ORC file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, orc

We have a requirement where we need to appednd `ORC` files. I tried to google it but no result. Also `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl` of `ORC` do not have the append API. Is there anyway to append the ORC files? (More specifically using JAVA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORC data files are subdivised in independent *stripes*; each stripe be created in a single atomic step. See [the official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC) for details.

I don't believe you can directly append to an existing file on-the-fly. That would mean leaving a corrupt stripe (hence a corrupt file) in case of a job crash while writing.

But you can

- create a new ORC data file (which will contain 1..N stripes depending
  on actual data volume vs. `orc.stripe.size` property) per reducer
- then "concatenate" these data files -- and existing file(s) -- using [Hive V0.14 and above](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate)